# Is there a way to detect that the login screen is active?

Tags: c++, windows

I have a member of my household who appears to be trying to get in to my PC while I'm asleep. I've decided to write a service which will load at startup, and will use the built-in camera to take a few snapshots of the culprit as soon as the login screen is displayed. Is this possible in Windows 8.1 and VS 2013? I tried using spy++ (with the "Always On Top" option) and then locking my computer to see if I could get more info, but as you'd imagine, the login screen stays top-most. I can't find a whole lot on MSDN about the lock/login-screen, either. Does anybody here have some info I could use?

Comment: this might be irrelevant, but why wouldn't you watch the position of mouse/chair before/after sleep or something like that?

Comment: Is that even necessary? Just run a service at startup that _always_ takes a few photos, and turn the computer off when you go to sleep. You should be doing that anyway to save energy. Or, since it's a member of your _household_ you should be able to just ask...

Comment: Well another option would be to detect a switch between sleep/wake states, then put the PC to sleep when I'm done for the night. This would also make debugging a hell of a lot easier. Is there like a set of WinAPI methods for this?

Comment: You might be able to use [this solution](http://superuser.com/questions/615330/webcam-automatically-takes-picture-when-the-computer-wakes-up).  You would probably have to change the task trigger from `When Workstation Unlock ` to `at startup`

Comment: It might be worth it to note that a few webcam shots are where I'd like to start off with this, but eventually, I'd like to start/stop video capturing. Start on startup for X amount of time, and start/stop on awake/sleep. I managed to find [THIS on MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa373196(v=vs.85).aspx) which may prove useful

Comment: Is a hardware solution acceptable? You could lock your door.

Comment: @TartanLlama No, that's not an option. It's not kept in a room with a door, let alone a lock.

Comment: @Damon I will ask them once I have enough evidence. This way, I can see where my trust lies with this individual.